# LTSpice display issue on osx

Tags: ltspice, spice

I'm knew to this site spice so please be gentle :)

I've installed LTSpice (LTspice XVII for OS X, Build Oct 25 2018, 14:56:22 US Pacific) on a MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6[image].

When I try to add anything to the schematic the display does not refresh and I get the remnants of moving the component across my schematic.  See the image for what I mean.

Hopefully someone can help me on this as I prefer to run a native tool rather than something in a vm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more digging around it seems that the latest version has problems with osx.

If you stumble across this post please refer to [Bug in LTSpice while moving component](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/406081/bug-in-ltspice-while-moving-component?rq=1)